# How can I "clean up" my migration files in my Rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My db/migrate folder has grown quite large. Every time I need to go edit a migration file prior to running `rake db:migrate` it is a slight annoyance to scroll through them all and find the file and then scroll back up to collapse the folder.  Is there a way to "clean up" this folder once it's gotten this large?  Perhaps a way to consolidate the files down or put them in a sub folder?

Comment: Well, why do you edit your migrations? That's not how you/we manage them. If you need any change to the schema, u add another migration to do the change, not the old one.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, I don't think that was the question. The question was how to manage the too many migration files in the `db/migrate` directory, without touching the schema.

Comment: @BoraMa It's a legit question--if the problem the OP is having is having to "scroll through them all and find the file to edit" it's an XY problem--the OP's problem is that they're using migrations "wrong", not that the directory is too large. It likely *is* too large, but IMO after certain stability points the answer isn't to move them, but to use a structure file and start basing migrations off of that.

Comment: @BoraMa I understood what OP asked, but I didn't like the approach of editing the migration files, which is wrong at first. So I didn't go ahead for later part.

Comment: @DaveNewton, @ArupRakshit Ah, I see your point now. If the OP edits old migration files, that would be of course a problem, but there are IMO valid cases for the files editing. I frequently edit a migration **before pushing it to the repo** and I do a few `db:migrate:redo` before that as my knowledge of the changes needed emerges. Also, I frequently need to *view* recent migrations and I like the idea of not having to scroll down that long to get there.

Comment: @BoraMa That's legit. Although I'd probably just sort by file date descending instead of scrolling, and if you're needing to edit beyond a recent migration or two I'd argue you're either not pushing enough, or not following good branching hygiene ;)

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, or maybe I'm just migrating too fast :). I just looked at our biggest project and there are nearly 500 migrations, most of them a few years old now. I still like the idea of moving them somewhere better than `ls -t | head`. Though, actually I'm using Rubymine where you indeed have to scroll to get down there...

Comment: @BoraMa Yeah, they pile up--but at some point IMO you stop building the DB from migrations, formalize it in a structure file, and can start migrating off of that new DB "base" structure.

Comment: Woah! this page blew up haha, sorry about the delay.  I don't edit old migrations, but if I generate a migration to add columns I usually have to go in and tweak them a bit like adding the null, default, limit attributes to the column.  That's what I was referring to.  Thanks for the information!

Comment: @DaveNewton interesting idea, I like it, though I don't like losing history and authorship of the original migrations. Sometimes I want to know whether a column was added way back or recently and who might have some deeper knowledge about it. I know, it's all in the repo history, but still... Anyway, thanks for this discussion!

Comment: @BoraMa I'm glad to know about the subfolders as well; I don't know if I ever knew that. A couple of counterpoints: http://homeonrails.com/2012/11/null-migration-or-what-to-do-when-there-are-too-many-migrations/ and http://naturaily.com/blog/post/how-to-remove-old-database-migrations-in-ruby-on-rails.. Good chat; thanks for the input.

Comment: @DaveNewton thanks for the links, maybe you should make this an answer so that it's more prominent here? I think they are relevant for the  OP's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can safely put old migrations into subfolders.

Check the [`needs_migration?` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L857) that is used to determine if a migration is needed to be run or all migrations are already applied. This method compares **all migration files** from the default `db/migrate` folder with all (already applied) migrations that are present in the **`schema_migrations` table** in the database. The point is that the **search for migration files is [recursive](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L886)**.

Compare for yourself the following tests. The test calls the [`migrations` method](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration.rb#L883) that returns the migrations defined on the file system and filters out the migration names.

```
ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrations(['db/migrate']).map(&:name)
# => ["CreateUsers", "CreateJobs", "AddBirthToUsers", "CreateDelayedJobs", ...]
```

Now move some of the migration files to a subfolder under `db/migrate` and repeat the same command and you will see that **the output is exactly the same** (you can e.g. count the number of returned entries). Thus, you can move migration files anywhere around under the main migration directory and they will behave the same for Rails.

**Update**: it didn't even occur to me, that you might have meant *editing* old migration files. You should *never* edit old migration files. Even a "consolidation" meaning "concatenating" old migration files would not work either, as the *timestamp* of the file determines the *version* of the migration (and using it the migrations are ordered). So, if it is understood that by cleaning the files you meant "getting them out of the way" when browsing them, you can move them to subfolders.

Comment: nope your initial answer was perfect.  I perhaps should have written my question more clearly. Much thanks my friend!